# Нахождения ближайшего здания (с адресом) в Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация

Разрабатываю приложние для таксопарка. Может кто в курсе, возможен ли такой финт:
1. Берем абсолютно рандомные координаты
2. Если эти координаты указывают на "пустоту", найти ближайшее здание (с адресом) к этой точке

Возможно ли это в принципе?

Дело в том, что в приложении хотелось бы дать возможность пользователю указать точки A и B не вводом адреса, а тапом по экрану. Как следствие, он может "промахнуться", т.е. тапнуть рядом со зданием
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: емнип у гугла геокодинг так по умолчанию и работает

Comment: Возможно вам поможет это руководство Гугл Поиск мест поблизости https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests